# i want check input by regex | contain 16 number

Tags: php, regex

I have input, I want to check it.

It should accept only numbers, and must be 16, no more and no less.

How I can do that using php and regex?

Comment: great site to help you learn: http://www.regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

Comment: i tryed to lrean it many times
but its complex can you make it for me?

Comment: @moustafa: what did you try and what happened? Can you post some code?

Comment: i just want the regex code to use perg_match or any other php function

Answer (score 3):

Regex would be `^\d{16}$`

```
preg_match("/^\\d{16}$/", $str);
```

Comment: IMO, it's better to use single quotes on matching string, since it prevents unexpected results, like forgetting to escape backslash or other special characters (namely $). Not that you made any of these mistakes, quite contrary. I had several nasty bugs that were due to using double quotes, and learned my lesson.

Comment: @mr.b Appreciate that. I hardly know PHP; learned it for answering some regex/flash related questions on SO. I assume `$` variables are not expanded in single quoted strings - lemme google for more details.

Comment: In this case it's not expanded since it's not followed by a letter(s), however, if you were to put $abc (for some reason), that *would* break your party. And no, single quoted strings do not expand variables.

Answer (score 2):

```
^\d{16}$
```

Explication:

- `^` for the beginning of the line (so nothing before that)
- `\d` meaning a number (decimbal)
- `{16}` to mean "exactly 16"
- `$` for the ending of the line (so nothing after that)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need it for the credit card validator

^(\d{4}[- ]){3}\d{4}|\d{16}$

this will match :

1234-1234-1234-1234 | 1234 1234 1234 1234 | 1234123412341234

Please note that this is copied from regexlib

Comment: If you are going to parse "real world formats", be lenient. Be friendly to your users. Remove everything that is not a number, parse the 16 numbers, then apply the format. This way even typo's like "12341234 1234.1234" get parsed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Would it not be better to make sure its 16 characters and numbers only with `is_numeric()` and `strlen()`.